# _csv.Error: newline in side string

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I'm using Python to extract some data from the forum's posting data set.
The data sets are like below:

```
"id"    "title" "tagnames"      "author_id"     "body"  "node_type"     "parent_id"     "abs_parent_id" "added_at"      "score" "state_string"  "last_edited_id"        "last_activity_by_id"   "last_activity_at"      "active_revision_id"    "extra" "extra_ref_id"  "extra_count"   "marked"
"5339"  "Whether pdf of Unit and Homework is available?"        "cs101 pdf"     "100000458"     ""      "question"      "\N"    "\N"    "2012-02-25 08:09:06.787181+00" "1"     ""      "\N"    "100000921"     "2012-02-25 08:11:01.623548+00" "6922"  "\N"    "\N"    "204"   "f"
"2312"  "Feedback on Audio Quality"     "cs101 production audio"        "100005361"     "

<p>We are looking for feedback on the audio in our videos. Tell us what you think and try to be as <em>specific</em> as possible.</p>" "question"      "\N"    "\N"    "2012-02-23 00:28:02.321344+00" "2"     ""      "\N"    "201398145"     "2014-01-14 17:18:35.613939+00" "2960"  "\N"    "\N"    "524"   "f"
```

As you could see, the body field of the post record may have multiple lines, so when I try to use my code below to extract the id of each post, it will complain and says `_csv.Error: newline in side string`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import csv

reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter = '\t')
for line in reader:
    print line[0]
```

Is there anyone knows any approach could solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./map.py", line 44, in <module>
    for line in reader:
_csv.Error: newline inside string
```

And the line 44 and 45 is:

```
"5413"  "Can you help me?"      "cs101 "        "100001316"     "<p>for I can not visit the udacity vedio pages,so can you help me to send me the CS101 Course Vedios via EMAIL.My Email is:<br>
@8765004</p>"   "question"      "\N"    "\N"    "2012-02-25 11:11:33.996285+00" "0"     "(closed)"      "25253" "100001316"     "2012-02-27 07:19:45.875472+00" "9089"  "\N"    "\N"    "230"   "t"^M
```

Comment: I think you are using the wrong tool for the job. That isn't a CSV file. You are getting that particular error because the dataset contains strings with the newline character in them. ( "\n" )

Comment: @Ittociwam Yeah, it's true that I could directly read per line from `stdin` without csv.reader, but the problem is still there, any suggestion to solve?

Comment: The code you've shown should just work. Quoted strings can contain newlines and the `csv` module should handle them just fine. Can you show the full traceback of the exception you're getting?

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for comments, but actually that's just full traceback I got, but I still add some more info maybe you would like to check.

Comment: Hmm, reading about that error suggest is has to do with Python's universal newlines handling interfering with the `csv` module's interpretation of the newlines itself. Unfortunately, since you're reading from `sys.stdin`, the usual fix of opening the input file in binary mode won't work. Frankly I have no idea what you can do to prevent universal newlines handling on stdin. Could you read your input some other way?